# Create questionnaire with multiple results based on answers

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a questionnaire in which I will ask the user 5 questions (maybe more in the future). These questions will have always 2 options and then I would like to show the results based on the different combinations.

Example:

A A B A B = Result A

B A B A B = Result B

A B A B A = Result C

...etc

My idea is to create an array with the different answers and then create a switch per case.

Am I in the good way or do you think there are better solutions? I'm not very advanced programmer but I need to do that using HTML and Javascript.

Thanks in advance for your help!
I.

Comment: I would expect the result to either be the percent of questions correctly answered or a list of the correct answers. What do you mean by Result?

Comment: @styfle what I mean is that the Result is a result based on the previous answers. Actually is a sort of a filter, for example:  question 1 --> mountain or beach? question 2 --> day or night? question 3 --> breakfast or dinner?. Then having for example, the answers "Beach", "night" and "dinner", the result will be a city or a restaurant or something else. Thanks in advance for your help! I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with radio buttons inside of a form. Use Javascript to get the value of the radio buttons and output the result. Here is an example of how you could do one of the questions:

```html
<html>
<h3>What do you choose?</h3>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="inputs" value="A" id="A" /> A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="inputs" value="B" id="B" /> B
</form>
<h3 id="out"></h3>
<button onclick="checkForm()">Submit</button>
<script>
function checkForm() { 
 if ((document.getElementById("A")).checked) {
  (document.getElementById("out")).innerHTML = "Value is A";
 }
 else {
  (document.getElementById("out")).innerHTML = "Value is B";
 }
 
}
</script>
</html>
```